# Ctrl+D keyboard shortcut stopped working?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has stopped working for me.

I use that shortcut all the time in Photoshop, Visual Studio, and many other apps. I have no clue why it would stop working.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key works fine by itself, so does the <kbd>D</kbd> key.

Even when I try to bind a macro to a hot key (Crimson Editor) it doesn't work with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> combination.

**What is the best way to diagnose and resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind!

It looks like the issue was **Screenshot Studio**. After closing this program, Ctrl+D started working normally again.

Hope this helps someone else!